# How to debug Node.js programs in eclipse (using node-eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am very newbie to eclipse as well as the node.js is concerned. I have tried several basic programs in node.js.

Now my question is there are many articles explaining how to debug the node program in eclipse. I dnt get it working. I am on windows 7 32-bit machine and installed eclipse Indigo with node-eclipse plugin installed..

Please can any body help me how to start debugging with programs.

Disclaimer: I am very new to eclipse IDE, Node & this stackover flow as well, please help..

Comment: As a long time Eclipse user, contributor, and lover, I would recommend against using Eclipse for JavaScript development.  For debugging, I use node-inspector.  I know that's not the answer you want to hear, but that's the only answer I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Debugging - Breakpoint, Trace, etc... via Eclipse [debugger plug-in
> for V8](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/)**

**How to Install:**

- Update Site : https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/
- Testing Site: http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/updates/

**How to debug**:

> Open the JavaScript source files that you want to set breakpoints.
>
> Double-click on the ruler at the left end of the line you want to set a breakpoint.
>
> If you want to remove a breakpoint, double-click on the ruler again.
>
> Select the main source file of Node Application on the Project Explorer, open the context menu by right-clicking, select the [Debug As]-[Node Application] menu.

- For more, Please Check [Nodeclipse](http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/) & [Using Eclipse as Node Applications Debugger](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates#nodeclipse-cli--installer)

Happy debugging ;)

Comment: The second link is dead now

Comment: First link is serving Chinese content?

Comment: @ankitkpd Thanks